# Electrical Induction, what are the cable limits before it becomes a problem

Tags: power-supply, power

I have a little hobby that has 3 power cables coming and going (each cable is 12V DC, 7.55 amp max).
Now these cables are ridiculously long (approx 5m+) and the equipment having to be mobile is small 0.5mx0.5x0.5.
Been looking at solutions to better cable management but nothing has stood out yet, most invovle having cables stretched out, which doesn't help me.
Now i am considering of creating 3 small spools that i can wrap each of the power cables on and then attach the spools to each other.
This is where i been advised to be careful of induction and to look into it.

Now considering the low power of these cables (the equipment is sensitive so doesn't consume large amounts of power) would my solution of creating 3 spools if power cables then attaching them together next to each other cause induction and thus problems or am I within safe limits to do this?

Comment: "doesn't consume large amounts of power" and "7.55 amp max" don't fit too well together for me. Also note that depending on the cables thickness, this can produce some heat that is dissipated easily when layed out, but builds up when on a spool.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Induction isn't the problem, even at 50Hz, and certainly not at DC, when winding a few metres of wire onto a spool. What IS a problem is heat : a wire in open air cools reasonably well, and the heat is spread out over its length. On a spool, the heat is concentrated and the inner turns of wire are insulated by the outer layers. Draw too much current - even though the wire is within its normal ratings - and ... well you don't want its insulation to melt.

If your equipment takes 7.5A, this may matter. If your wires are rated for 7.5A but the equipment takes a couple of amps or less, you'll be fine.

Comment: Thanks Brian, the cabling is rated at 7.5A and has regulated PSU on it (equipment is sensitive). Equipment max usage is 5A per cable, it is used only at night time outdoors, so far have not noticed any heat on cables, but only on PSU (which is a bit away from actual cable). I am assuming should be fine to spool them up based on that?

Comment: @Aeseir: Your assumption may be wrong. Single cable outdoors cools incredibly much faster than the inside of a spooled cable. You should calculate the power loss within that cable and that is a number that can be used to say more.

Comment: @PlasmaHH thanks mate, to clarify the spool i have designed will ensure there is no cables doubling up over each other, but are neatly lined up next to each other. From what i been told the power loss is minimal and so far I can advise that i have not had any issues with heating or power loss. But i will keep an eye out in tests i do before I mount it.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the problem in the first answer you also need to take the voltage drop into account for low voltages. 15AWG for example has a resistance of 0.0102Ω/m which causes a voltage drop of 2*5m*0.0102Ω*7.55A = 0.77V or roughly 6%. So there's only 11.2V left for your 'little hobby' device. If it has operational problems with such drop use thicker wire.